# Novatel SDK (windows)

Tags: visual-c++, sdk, wireless

I installed the novatel SDK for windows and attempted to run an example application (FieldTestInfo).

I made sure to check if the NvtlService is running in windows services (it is).

When I run in debug, I see that:

```
//Check to see if SDK loaded okay
    if( !sdk.IsLoaded() )
    {
        printf("SDK unavailable, aborting\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

sdk.IsLoaded returns false.

Nothing in the sdk addresses this. Anyone know what I should check to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Check the documentation - there must be some method to "Load".

Comment: there is. It says "Load dll by running Ntlsvr in command line" Which I did, but the isLoaded function still returns false!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is to avoid using Novatel products if you are concerned with documentation and an active developer community. Novatel offers neither.

I contacted Sierra wireless and so far have had a much easier time obtaining the information required to develop applications equivalent to those I would have used novatel product for.